# What are the benefits of the different Tiers?

Tags: runes-of-magic

Simple enough,

weapons, armor, runes, and fusion stones have different Tiers, how do they affect each piece of gear. How are these tiers obtained?

Comment: why don t you notice my answers?

Comment: @Ekonion I noticed them just wasn't impressed with your answers, they seem lazy and just give me more questions then answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple example, you have a tier four two handed staff, and you think its quite good. but not as good as you want. What do you do? correct, upgrade it. You take manastones with a tier, at least one level above the one of your "to-uprade" gear, in this example at least tier five manastones. You need three of them. Put them altogether in the arcane transmutor, add the staff, and voila, you have instead of a tier four staff a little better tier five staff. It affects your staff by the following: Your MAT and PAT is raised a little and a green-stat is added or raised, too (just by a few points) that is how to tier-up.